# changing scroll bar color using css

Tags: css, windows

can we give different color to scroll bar face color and arrow background ?

right now if I apply " scrollbar-face-color " it is applying to both arrow background as well as scroll bar thump

is there any way to Set the color for the scroll bar slider and the boxes that contain the scrollbar arrows differently

Comment: Is it really necessary? Leave it up to the user to decide if they want to colour their own scrollbars.

Answer (score 1):

body {
   scrollbar-arrow-color: green
}

I think that only IE supports coloured scrollbars by the way.

See here for a full list - http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/coloring_scrollbars_using_styles_css_properties.php3

Comment: Yup, this is a nice way but it's IE only.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in  a cross browser way. Use custom elements and apply CSS and javascript to act like scrollable areas.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ?

[Cross Browser Custom Scrollbars](http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar#testedbrowsers)